# Got a `TypeError` when calling `Article.objects.create()`

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am working on Django React Project using the Django REST FRAMEWORK,I am trying to post some data tied to my model.

The list view and the detail view of the project works pretty fine,The only problem is when I try to make a POST request.

Whenever I Try post the data in the CreateAPIView I get an error :

```
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Article.objects.create()`.  This may be because 
you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to
`Article.objects.create()`.  You may need to make the field read-only, or override
the ArticleSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

I have searched through various past problems but non of them seem to fix my problem.

Here is my serializers file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from articles.models import Article

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id','title','content','star_count','like_count','comment_count','avatar')
```

Here is my views file

```
from rest_framework.generics import  ListAPIView,RetrieveAPIView,CreateAPIView,UpdateAPIView,DestroyAPIView
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer
from articles.models import Article
from rest_framework import viewsets



class ArticleViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

models file

```
    content = models.TextField()
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    star_count = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article,self).save()
```

Here is the error generated when I try to make a POST request based on the django rest framework createAPIVew

```
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Article.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Article.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ArticleSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
```

Comment: Does `Article.objects.create()` work if not using POST but shell, django view, or unittests instead ? It seams like title and slug are missing from your model.

Comment: Can you show the whole Article model? Does it have a `title` field?

Comment: yes It has an title field

Comment: Class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,null=True,blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    like_count = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    star_count = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)

Comment: def  __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article,self).save()

Comment: Kindly update your question to contain the full code rather than commenting.

Comment: save method in your model is incorrect. It should looks like save(self, *args, **kwargs): and in super method call super(Article,self).save(*args, **kwargs)